# AVAudioRecord prepareRecord & Record returns NO

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder

I'm currently working on a game project, which supports audio recording. this program is based on WiEngine , a game engine kinda like cocos2d-x.

here's the thing , I've tried many ways , but EVERY time I called [myRecorder Record] it always returns NO. then I called PrepareRecord explicitly , it returns No either.

here's the code how I init the Recorder

```
- (void)initRecorder
{
    if(self.myRecoder!=nil)
    {
        [self.myRecoder release];
        self.myRecoder=nil;
    }


    NSDictionary *myRecorderParam = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0],AVSampleRateKey,
                                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM],AVFormatIDKey,
                                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
                                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMedium],AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                     nil];

    NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *DocumentPath = [pathArray objectAtIndex:0];
    DocumentPath = [DocumentPath stringByAppendingString:@"/luyin.wav"];

    self.myRecoder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:DocumentPath]
                                                settings:myRecorderParam
                                                   error:nil];


    [self.myRecoder setDelegate:self];

}
```

and I called Record like this

```
- (void)beginRecord
{
    NSLog(@"begin record");

//    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
//    NSError *err = nil;
//    [audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
//    if(err){
//        NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
//        return;
//    }
//    err = nil;
//    [audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
//    if(err){
//        NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
//        return;
//    }

    if(self.myRecoder==nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"recoder null");
    }

    BOOL resultPre = [[self myRecoder] prepareToRecord];
    if(resultPre)
    {
        NSLog(@" record pre yes ");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@" record pre no ");
    }

    BOOL result = [[self myRecoder] record];
    if(result)
    {
        NSLog(@" record yes ");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@" record no ");
    }
}
```

according to the NSLogs , I’m sure that the initialization does not seem to fail.

I also tried to init an AudioSession , but it doesn't work either

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0):

is it AVAudioRecorder ?

AVAudioPlayer is use for play Record

Like this:

NSMutableDictionary* recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];

[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[freq.text floatValue]] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: [value.text intValue]] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

recordedTmpFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.0f.%@", [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] * 1000.0, @"caf"]]];
NSLog(@"Using File called: %@",recordedTmpFile);
recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:recordedTmpFile settings:recordSetting error:&error];

Comment: Sorry , I got another code pasted. now I edited it , it is AVAudioRecorder